# How to force Mathematica to clean up the cache

Tags: memory

*(see the bottom of this question for the MWE)*

I'm working with a set of numerical data: numerous (a few thousands) files in the style of list of vectors (quadruplets x, y, vx, vy). Files are named as v1.txt, v2.txt, ..., vk.txt, where k is a few thousands. I am using For loop in Mathematica, in each cycle several steps are performed:

```
1) load vi.txt
2) make list of pairs of pairs from it (in the form of {{x1, y1},{v1x, v1y}, ...})
3) construct absolute value of the vector field ({{x1, y1}, norm of {v1x, v1y}, ...})
4) Make list density plot of the absolute value list
5) Make list stream plot of the pairs of pairs
6) export both.
```

The problem is that after about 200 cycles, Mathematica sucks up all the physical memory available in my machine and the kernel crashes. I tried using:

```
1) $HistoryLength = 0
2) ClearSystemCache[] after every cycle
3) ClearAll[(plots, data)] after every cycle
4) all of the above combined
```

up to no avail. What am I doing wrong? What should I do to tell Mathematica to get rid of the images from the previous step, so it won't suck up all of my RAM? The code I'm using is as follows:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Monitor[
 For[i = 1, i <= 5383, i++,
  v = Partition[
    Partition[
     Flatten@Import["output\\results\\v" <> ToString[i] <> ".txt", 
       "Table"], 2], 2];
  Absv = Table[{v[[i, 1, 1]], v[[i, 1, 2]], Norm[v[[i, 2]]]}, {i, 1, 
     Length@v}];
  LDP = ListDensityPlot[Absv, PlotRange -> Full, 
    ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"SolarColors", "Reverse"}], 
    MaxPlotPoints -> 100, ImageSize -> 1000];
  LSP = ListStreamPlot[v, StreamStyle -> White, StreamPoints -> Fine, 
    StreamScale -> 0.1, ImageSize -> 1000];
  Export["output\\results\\img" <> ToString[i] <> ".png", LDP];
  Export["output\\results\\img_stream" <> ToString[i] <> ".png", Show[LDP, LSP]];
  ClearSystemCache[];
  ClearAll[v,Absv,LDP,LSP];
  ], i]
```

Why is Mathematica completely ignoring all statements [`$HistoryLength`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$HistoryLength.html), [`ClearSystemCache`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClearSystemCache.html) and [`ClearAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClearAll.html)?

#### MWE

This is a minimal working example demonstrating my problem (not depending on any mysterious data that I have on my HDD):

```
MemoryInUse[]
Do[
  ListStreamPlot@
   Table[{{Random[], Random[]}, {Random[], Random[]}}, 1000];
  ClearSystemCache[],
  {i, 10}
  ];
MemoryInUse[]
```

[Together with Henrik](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43195419#43195419) we figured out [`ListStreamPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListStreamPlot.html) is the culprit, therefore I reported this as a bug.

Comment: Hard to say. The code looks okay to me. You could also try to wrap the body of the loop in a `Module` and scope all temporary variables within, so that they get cleared by automatic garbage collection.

Comment: Maybe one of the built-in functions has a memory leak. You could narrow down the problematic part of the code by commenting out various parts of the loop's body and see if the memory leak persists. Should you find one, I would advise you to contact the support.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: could you please expand on that Module idea? By looking at the documentation, I don't quite get what I should do inside the loop...Module[{v, Absv, LDP, LSP}, the body of the loop]? This does exactly the same thing as before: my memory eventually leaks.

Comment: Aha. Okay, I did not really expect it to help. You did exactly what I meant. Next step would be to identify where exactly the mess happens. I would not be supprised, if it happens with the `Import/Export` calls...

Comment: If nothing else helps, chop the `For` loop into several smaller chunks and use `Exit[]` in between to restart the kernel. Only a workaround of course...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Not sure if I've gotten your idea, but I wrapped the export (to image) calls in comments and the result is the same: memory leak. Of course, no images are produced, just a bunch of memory is wasted on...something. So the culprit is not the export call. I don't know how to try the import calls: if I comment out the import calls there wouldn't be any data left to make plots from, so the loop would produce just a bunch of errors. Can't I use that Exit[] clause at the end of the For cycle (or would it be too slow)?

Comment: Aha. It's the `Import` then. You could play with it by using different export filters (instead of `"Table"`) such as `"Text"`, `"Data"`, `"CSV"` what not. Maybe you find one that uses a different, hopefully leak-free backend... Thinking about it: Can you also try to strip the `Monitor`?These `Dynamic` things also feel a bit suspicious. You can use `If[Mod[i,100]==0,Print[i]];` instead for monitoring.

Comment: Okay, I tried Data, up to no avail. I also tried Text and CSV, however I have no clue how to convert those to proper numeric data inside Mathematica (Text produces just a huge string of numbers divided by space which I don't know how to chop into table again, CSV behaves weirdly when I try to apply partition to it (it won't chop it into pairs of pairs as it did with "Table" option). Also, removing monitor did nothing regarding the memory leak.

Comment: What about the memory with the `"Text"`? If the leak persists then we do not have to worry about conversion...

Comment: I changed "Table" to "Text", however I had to remove flatten and partition (asi those are not interpreted correctly and produce a bunch of errors). I also had to comment out everything after that Import clause, as the rest works with the imported data (not possible if the data is string)...with this version (only imported as text), there are no memory leaks. However, keep in mind I commented the rest of the cycle, only import was left. How can I shape the imported string into tabular expression as intended originally?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74004/discussion-between-henrik-schumacher-and-user16320).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Note that I can reproduce your MWE replacing all the `ListStreamPlot` stuff with just `ListPlot@Table[RandomReal[], 250]; ClearSystemCache[]; MemoryInUse[]` which is coming from some faulty caching of the compiled `Table` as `ListPlot@Table[RandomReal[], 249]; ClearSystemCache[]; MemoryInUse[]` doesn't do this

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is also not an answer (I think you found the culprit and it needs to be solved by WRI) but a suggestion for a workaround. The idea is to run the memory leaking code in an extra kernel and restart that kernel every once in a while. Using the parallel functionality of current Mathematica releases this is pretty simple and by choosing an appropriate value for the number of parallel kernels you could even take advantage of parallelism if desired.

Here is a simple example based on your minimal working example which demonstrates the idea and shows that the master kernel will not accumulate any memory:

```
LaunchKernels[1];
Print[MemoryInUse[]];
calcsPerKernel = 3;
Do[
   With[{fname = "plot-" <> ToString[i] <> ".png"},
     ParallelEvaluate[
       Export[
         FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", fname}],
         ListStreamPlot[
           Table[{{Random[], Random[]}, {Random[], Random[]}}, 1000]
         ]
       ];
       Print[MemoryInUse[]];
     ]
   ];
   If[Mod[i, calcsPerKernel] == 0,
     CloseKernels[];
     ClearSystemCache[];
     LaunchKernels[1];
   ];
   ,
  {i, 10}
];
CloseKernels[];
ClearSystemCache[];
Print[MemoryInUse[]];
```

The idea for a more general and flexible approach is as follows:

- use `LaunchKernels` to launch the desired number of parallel kernels
- use `ParallelSubmit` to pass the computations (e.g. per file) to the parallel kernel(s)
- use `WaitNext` to get the result of a computation from the other kernel(s).
- use `CloseKernels[kernelid]` and `LaunchKernels` to restart a/the parallel kernels

As it is very difficult to completely avoid memory leaks in sufficient complex Mathematica code I think this is a technique that will be helpful in many situations. We are using this approach regularly for computations that run for several days and have found that it works very reliable. Unlike some other parts of Mathematica the parallel toolkit seems to work very stable and reliable even on a larger scale.

Comment: As you're the only one who have come up with something that works, I'm giving you a thumbs up and I accept this as an answer. Using your wrapper I'm exporting 5 different plots each step and I get no memory leaks (only using about 1GB of memory) - I can see the memory refresh after each step in my task manager. Thanks and keep up the good work!

Comment: as I said, it is just a workaround but it has proven to be useful for me in many cases. Good to hear it works for you and thanks for the accept...

Comment: Oh, one more thing: why neither of $HistoryLength, CleanAll, CleanSystemCache work in my example? I thought those are supposed to get rid of unneeded stuff left in memory...

Comment: there are countless possibilities for memory leaks which are not covered by the above. In your case it looks like leaks in the autocompilation code and `ListStreamPlot` as the other answers demonstrates. There probably is nothing you can do about that despite not using that functionality or wait for WRI to correct it. Because that situation is not so unusual (and that is true when using other systems/libraries as well) I thought the given workaround might be of wider interest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The workaround you provided is very useful.

Answer (score 10):

#### Not an answer, just extended clarification

There seem to be many types of caching related leaks here.

I can get one by just doing this:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
Do[Table[RandomReal[], 251], 200]
ClearSystemCache[];
MemoryInUse[]
```

Calling that repeatedly shows a steady increase with brief pauses.

This doesn't cause a leak:

```
Do[Table[RandomReal[], 249], 200]
ClearSystemCache[];
MemoryInUse[]
```

Which shows that something is leaking in the internal auto-compilation.

These are yet distinct from what happens if you apply `ListPlot` to that. This causes a leak every call:

```
Do[ListPlot@Table[RandomReal[], 251], 5]
ClearSystemCache[];
MemoryInUse[]
```

While this continues not to leak:

```
Do[ListPlot@Table[RandomReal[], 249], 5]
ClearSystemCache[];
MemoryInUse[]
```

On the other hand if we use `ListStreamPlot` the leaks seem to be at top-level as this:

```
Do[ListStreamPlot@
    Table[RandomReal[{}, {2, 2}], 2];, 2];
ClearSystemCache[];
MemoryInUse[]
```

Leaks every single time

Comment: Hm. The first two do not leak on my machine (v. 11.0.1 for macos). But `ListStreamPlot@Table[RandomReal[{}, {2, 2}], 2]` leaks exactly 132752 Byte each time I execute it.