# Memory leak in the system function: how to free memory without restarting the kernel?

Tags: core-language, memory

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
```

Warming up:

```
TextSentences[StringJoin@RandomChoice[Join[Alphabet["Russian"], {" ", "."}], 100]];
```

**No memory leak:**

```
MemoryInUse[]
```

> 118502448

```
Do[
 StringJoin@RandomChoice[Join[Alphabet["Russian"], {" ", "."}], 100],
 {i, 10000}
 ]
```

```
MemoryInUse[]
```

> 118502448

**Memory leak in `TextSentences`:**

```
Do[
 TextSentences[StringJoin@RandomChoice[Join[Alphabet["Russian"], {" ", "."}], 100]],
 {i, 10000}
 ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {32.6916,Null}

```
MemoryInUse[]
```

> 260521400

**How to free memory without restarting the kernel?**

**Possible workaround (but very slow - up to 5x):**

```
LaunchKernels[1];

MemoryInUse[]
```

> 263313480

```
Do[
  ParallelEvaluate@TextSentences[StringJoin@RandomChoice[Join[Alphabet["Russian"], {" ", "."}], 100]],
  {i, 10000}
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {161.063, Null}

```
MemoryInUse[]
```

> 263313480

Comment: Check the help files for `Share`

Comment: @BillWatts Thank you for your comment! `Share` will not help. [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167102) is the good answer. But I am looking for a workaround without parallel kernel.

Answer (score 13):

Please report this to support. You can get rid of some of the memory leak by executing the following:

```
cleanupTextSentences[] := Remove[
    "NaturalLanguageProcessing`TextCases`PackagePrivate`interpretations$@",
    "NaturalLanguageProcessing`TextCases`PackagePrivate`probabilities$@",
    "NaturalLanguageProcessing`TextPosition`PackagePrivate`punctuationPositions$@",
    "NaturalLanguageProcessing`TextPosition`PackagePrivate`tokenPositions$@",
    "NaturalLanguageProcessing`TextPosition`PackagePrivate`wordPositions$@"
]
```

Your example:

```
MemoryInUse[]

Do[
    TextSentences[StringJoin@RandomChoice[Join[Alphabet["Russian"], {" ", "."}], 100]],
    {i, 10000}
] // AbsoluteTiming

MemoryInUse[]

cleanupTextSentences[]
MemoryInUse[]
```

> 123158784
>
> {26.6266, Null}
>
> 231403704
>
> 167386720

If you want to use parallel processing, why not use [`ParallelDo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelDo)?

```
MemoryInUse[]

ParallelDo[
    TextSentences[StringJoin@RandomChoice[Join[Alphabet["Russian"],{" ","."}],100]],
    {i,10000}
] //AbsoluteTiming

MemoryInUse[]
```

> 182588776
>
> {7.46125, Null}
>
> 182591464

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Already reported. I will process my data sequentially. Do you know a workaround for ANY system function that may have a memory leak?