# Running out of RAM because of a loop

Tags: mesh, memory

I'm working with some Voronoi diagrams, and I want to find the perimeter and area of each polygon in it. I think I accomplish that, but I have a problem with RAM memory management. This is a simplification of the code, but suppose that after I analyze a diagram, I want to create a perturbation of it, and compute the perimeter and area again. I do this in the Do loop, adding noise to the set of points. The problem is that the RAM used increases after each iteration, and I don't know why, because each variable is being overwritten (I guess). I need to stop this constant increase, as the full code will use a couple of GB. I've noticed that calling the perimeter function increase the RAM usage noticeably, but I guess the problem is with all the graphical part. I would appreciate any advice.

````
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];
$HistoryLength = 0;

pts = {{48, 498}, {76, 491}, {146, 511}, {197, 528}, {239, 509}, {291, 498}, {355, 528}, {375, 493}, {452, 507}, {508, 512}, {45, 435}, {84, 463}, {138, 475}, {194, 491}, {250, 470}, {302, 437}, {357, 484}, {401, 457}, {461., 451.}, {509., 442.}, {63.4, 407.}, {84.9, 382.}, {108., 407.}, {197., 415.}, {239., 389.}, {307., 408.}, {339., 411.}, {413., 401.}, {451., 399.}, {540., 406.}, {21.6, 349.}, {83.5, 336.}, {118., 345.}, {175., 354.}, {248., 343.}, {309., 374.}, {349., 
358.}, {411., 322.}, {454., 335.}, {518., 371.}, {35.8, 290.}, {102., 320.}, {140., 320.}, {218., 285.}, {229., 286.}, {304., 306.}, {348., 304.}, {405., 293.}, {453., 287.}, {484., 287.}, {13.2, 248.}, {99.2, 238.}, {157., 237.}, {225., 233.}, {260., 235.}, {326., 278.}, {376., 242.}, {422., 238.}, {468., 243.}, {519., 238.}, {45.4, 203.}, {93.6, 191.}, {142., 189.}, {198., 180.}, {249., 
205.}, {300., 184.}, {349., 168.}, {405., 192.}, {458., 207.}, {508., 184.}, {30.2, 130.}, {74.1, 154.}, {120., 140.}, {177., 145.}, {239., 138.}, {292., 118.}, {334., 148.}, {376., 141.}, {442., 137.}, {519., 109.}, {19.3, 88.9}, {83.5, 106.}, {141., 90.}, {206., 98.7}, {262., 99.4}, {295., 92.}, {350., 104.}, {396., 100.}, {457., 89.7}, {506., 78.8}, {19.2, 69.8}, {61.2, 24.}, {116., 36.3}, {186., 37.8}, {242., 37.1}, {310., 32.4}, {343., 51.}, {415., 30.2}, {464., 43.4}, {506., 26.3}};

polyInsideMesh[z_, x_] := ContainsAll[z[[ConvexHull[z]]], Apply[#[[ConvexHull[#]]] &, {Join[z, x]}]];

perim[m_, v_] := Part[RegionMeasure /@ (MeshPrimitives[v, 2] /. Polygon[{x_, y__}] :> Line[{x, y, x}]), m];

area[m_, v_] := Part[PropertyValue[{v, 2}, MeshCellMeasure], m];

Do[
 npts = Length[pts];
 pts = pts + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {npts, 2}];
 vor = VoronoiMesh[pts]; (*Find Voronoi diagram*)
 hull = ConvexHullMesh[pts];(*Convex hull of the set of points*)
 mvor = MeshPrimitives[vor, 2];
 mhull = MeshCoordinates[hull];

 (*Get polygons inside the convex hull*)
 out = Show[Graphics /@ Select[mvor, polyInsideMesh[mhull, CoordinateBoundingBox[#]] &]] //    DiscretizeGraphics;
 len = Length[Graphics /@ Select[mvor, polyInsideMesh[mhull, CoordinateBoundingBox[#]] &]];

 (*Compute perimeter and area of the polygons inside the hull*)
 meana = Mean[Table[area[m, out], {m, 1, len}]];
 meanp = Mean[Table[perim[m, out], {m, 1, len}]];

 Print[i, ": ", meana, ", ", meanp], {i, 1, 100}]

```
````

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Diagnostics

I have spent quite some time debugging what I though was some kind of a memory leak in your loop. Indeed, we can see that in each iteration the memory increasas for ~3 MB:

```
mem = MemoryInUse[];
Do[
 Print[MemoryInUse[] - mem];
 mem = MemoryInUse[];
 ...
];

(* 9480
   12519624
   3120088
   3127008
   3126752 ... *)
```

I thought the reason was in some kind of internal caching system used in `RegionMeasure` or `MeshPrimitives`, because indeed `perim` seemed to be causing the biggest increase in memory. However, neither `ClearSystemCache[]` nor any other ways of clearing the cache worked.

### Solution

Then I looked at your code more closely and implemented a very simple and obvious shortening of your code: I removed `Table` and `Part` when calculating mean area and perimeter.

```
perim[v_] := RegionMeasure /@ (MeshPrimitives[v, 2] /. Polygon[{x_, y__}] :> Line[{x, y, x}]);
area[v_] := PropertyValue[{v, 2}, MeshCellMeasure];

mem = MemoryInUse[];
Do[
 Print[MemoryInUse[] - mem];
 mem = MemoryInUse[];
 npts = Length[pts];
 pts = pts + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {npts, 2}];
 vor = VoronoiMesh[pts];(*Find Voronoi diagram*)
 hull = ConvexHullMesh[pts];(*Convex hull of the set of points*)
 mvor = MeshPrimitives[vor, 2];
 mhull = MeshCoordinates[hull];
 (*Get polygons inside the convex hull*)
 out = Show[Graphics /@ Select[mvor, polyInsideMesh[mhull, CoordinateBoundingBox[#]] &]] // DiscretizeGraphics;
 len = Length[Graphics /@ Select[mvor, polyInsideMesh[mhull, CoordinateBoundingBox[#]] &]];
 (*Compute perimeter and area of the polygons inside the hull*)
 meana = Mean[area[out]];
 meanp = Mean[perim[out]];
, {i, 1, 10}]

(* 4920
   159424
   150080
   158192
   158656 ... *)
```

Great! Each iteration now increases the memory only for ~150 kB!

### Conclusion

I still suspect `MeshPrimitives` (or `RegionMeasure`) is somehow caching the results, but now it is evaluated only once per iteration and not `len` times per iteration so the overall memory increase is significantly smaller.

I hope this solution is good enough for your code to be run on your computer. Otherwise, let me know and I can try to find some further performance improvements.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed, this solution is good enough, and the code runs a lot faster! I'm still curious what's really going on with the cache, but I've also tried clearing it and failed.

Comment: In addition to your solution, I also implemented this, in case de 150 kb per loop becomes a problem: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167102/80954

Comment: I was also looking at this thread and possible usage of parallel evaluation, but I thought you needed to have sequential evaluation, because you sequentially perturbate points.

Comment: Yes. But I only launch one kernel and the only thing I do inside ParallelEvaluate is to compute meana and meanp. The perturbation of the points is outside ParallelEvaluate, so it's still sequential.